# Get versions updates of internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs4.1

Please I want to get  "versions updates" of internet explorer ,i'm using Ext js and i found a problem with IE who had version updates less than 9.0.28

Thanks .

here is an image to see which information i want to get:

[image: About Internet Explorer]

Comment: What does "Versions des mises à jour" mean?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario "Update Versions".

Comment: Is it a list of Windows Update releases that the end user is eligible for? Does not look like the typical information the browser would reveal. If you type `navigator` in the console you'll see the available properties, that might give you some clues.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following microsoft link to know more about the versions.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393